# Точность замера выполения программы

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Требуется замерить программу с высокой точностью и не через библиотеку Chrono, так как требуется строгая мерка выполнения подключаемой библиотеки с функциями на процессоре. Предложили вариант замерять через такты процессора, т.е. через **RDTSC**, и в целом то можно закончить, но замер, мягко говоря не очень. Ниже пример кода.

```
unsigned __int32 fstEnter = 0, secEnter = 0, average = 0; 

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {        
        __asm {
            xor eax, eax
            rdtsc
            mov [fstEnter], eax }

        someDll(...); // Обращение к библиотеке

        __asm {
            xor eax, eax
            rdtsc
            mov [secEnter], eax }
        average = average + secEnter - fstEnter; // Среднее
    }
```

Видел пару статей на эту тему, но увы, вся работа происходит под управлением Windows. 
Можно ли как-то запретить прерывать программу, запретить мигрировать программе на ядрах, выдать максимальный приоритет обработки? Интересует именно точное получение времени выполнения на процессоре.

Comment: возможно вам поможет vtune, при работе с tsc можно попробовать дать программе приоритет realtime

Comment: Вообще-то chrono (high_resolution_clock) работает через QueryPerformanceCounter, каковую MS очень рекомендуют, а про rdtsc пишут, что *We strongly discourage using the RDTSC or RDTSCP processor instruction to directly query the TSC because you won't get reliable results on some versions of Windows, across live migrations of virtual machines, and on hardware systems without invariant or tightly synchronized TSCs. Instead, we encourage you to use QPC to leverage the abstraction, consistency, and portability that it offers.* Так что большие у меня сомнения, что `crono` - это плохо :)

Comment: Запускайте 1000000 раз и засекайте общее время, делите на 1000000 - получаете время одного вызова.

Comment: С учётом того, что тестирование обязательно должно быть на windows, то через небольшой скриптик программа и запускалась с командами -REALTIME -WAIT через PowerShell (колхозный метод, лень писать больше).

Comment: По поводу Chrono - попробую ещё прожужать мозг человеку, но он упрямо не хочет его принимать и считает RDTSC прям золотым жилом, хотя не раз объяснял, что на современных процессорах он своё отжил. Вернуться лет на 20 назад и он был бы актуален.

Comment: По поводу огромного запуска - смешно, но так и делаем, но с оговоркой. Идея в том, что при больших значениях как раз достигается прирост в 2-3 раза, что удалось замерить с помощью Chrono в наносекундах, но вот человеку прям надо, чтоб была именно эта функция

Comment: Наверное перед вторым вызовом rdtsc нужен какой-то барьерчик. Хотя, в современных процессорах со спекулятивным исполнением команд для небольших последовательностей  мы всегда не очень хорошо понимаем, что именно измеряем... В общем, я бы прочел Т1 перед циклом, а после цикла сделал барьер по инструкциям (опустошил конвейер), прочел T2 и разделил `T2 - T1` на число итераций

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге всё же удалось сделать замеры времени через данную операцию. Но сразу, две особенности:

1.
При использовании __rdtsc вы не заметите миграцию между ядрами, а это может быть важно (разница в паре тактов). Необходимо использовать __rdtscp. Пример:

```
int cpuStart = 0, cpuFinish = 0;
int64 start = 0, finish = 0;
start = __rdtscp(&cpuStart);
//код
finish = __rdtscp(&cpuFinish);
finish = finish - start;
```

Это приблизительный код, сейчас точно не вспомню как именно.

Соответственно, чтобы посмотреть на каких ядрах было вычисление, через cout получить cpu. Объявлять обязательно (а то выскочит черти что).

2.Так же, нюанс (а из-за него и появился косвенно этот вопрос). Функция rand() не выдавала случайные значения должны образом и пришлось отдельно генерировать файл с этими значениями.